# Replacing all "0" and "?" in my dataset with NA except the response variable with "0" and "1' ( factors) using R

Tags: missing-data

[Here is an example of what my dataset looks like, though large with over 7,000 observation with 64 variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VP3qC.png).

Answer (score 0):

That's in Excel, right?

You can simply highlight "X#" columns, go to Edit -> Find -> Replace and use that tool to replace all "0" and "?" with "NA". Be sure to enable the "Find entire cells only" option.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I appreciate your quick response. I omitted an important information that the software in question is R-software and not excel.